# ncurses: detect a printable charcter with keypad on

Tags: perl, ncurses

I have `keypad` set to 1 because I want more control over the characters that are entered (e.g. in example below I want to detect a `KEY_DOWN`. This does not work if I have `keypad` off). However, I need to detect if a character is printable. I thought I could use `[[:print:]]` but I have misunderstood something. For example, if I run the following MWE and I enter backspace, I get output of `263` whereas I would like output `not printable`. I can try to address this by conditioning on `length(character) == 1` but this seems like a hack that I should avoid and I would like to learn the correct way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Curses;

initscr();
my $good_win = newwin(1, 2, 3, 1);
keypad($good_win, 1);

my $character = $good_win->getch();

if ($character eq KEY_DOWN) {
    print "you did a down arrow";
}

if ($character =~ "[[:print:]]") {
    print "you entered: $character\n";
}

else {
    print "not printable\n";
}

exit();
```

Note that I am a newbie with curses and with input character handling (you do not need to take pity in criticism, but I say this just so you know that I don't really know what I'm doing and would be appreciative of any detailed explanations).

Comment: Doesn't `getch()` return an integer? Then it would always be printable.

Answer (score 0):

`getch` doesn't return the ordinary the character codes that `[[:print:]]` contains, for special keys (it does for letters, numbers etc).

To test for backspace you need to test for `KEY_BACKSPACE` which is the 263 you got.

I don't think any of the special key codes are printable so any returned code greater or equal to `KEY_MIN` (the minimum special key code) will be not printable. Other values can be checked with `[[:print:]]`